# Logistic regression and log-inear

Tags: regression, logistic, log-linear

I do not know why log-linear is non-sensitive margins and logistic regression is sensitive margins. Both are using odds ratios Can anyone give some explanation.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more what you mean when you say "is non-sensitive margin"

Comment: Log-linear models are defined by margins free. In a contingency table, margins cannot impact on the set of odds ratios